# Perl SOAP::Lite WebService call with complex parameters

Tags: perl, soap, soaplite

I have to send a SOAP request in the following format:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acc="...">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acc:CreateChildSubscriptionAccount>
         <account>
            ...
         </account>
         <accountHierarchy>
            ...
         </accountHierarchy>
      </acc:CreateChildSubscriptionAccount>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The confusing point is being on how to make account and accountHierarchy to be at the same level in the request body.

I've tried so, this way:

```
sub callservice{
    ...
    $params =
        SOAP::Data->name(
            'accountHierarchy' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                SOAP::Data->name( 'customerId' => '250001' ),

                SOAP::Data->name( 'currencyCodeId' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                    SOAP::Data->name( 'domain' => 'ACC' ),
                    SOAP::Data->name( 'value' => 'EUR' )

                ) )
            )
        ),

        SOAP::Data->name(
            'account' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                SOAP::Data->name( 'customerId' => '250001' ),

                SOAP::Data->name( 'languageCodeId' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                    SOAP::Data->name( 'domain' => 'ACC' ),
                    SOAP::Data->name( 'value' => 'en' )

                ) ),

                SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleProgression' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                    SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleEntry' => \SOAP::Data->value(
                        SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleSubState'=> 'STD' ),
                        SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleReasonCode'=> 'ADD' ),
                        SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleState'=> 'ACTIVE' )
                    ) )

                )),

                SOAP::Data->name( 'paymentResponsibility' => 'true' ),

                SOAP::Data->name( 'accountName' => 'TLA13134' ),

                SOAP::Data->name( 'accountType' => 'CONVERGENT' )

            )
        );

    $response = $service->call("createChildSubscriptionAccount", $params);
}
```

but it is failing, as it only sends the last SOAP::Data->value defined in the structure which is `accountHierarchy` in this case.

Would anyone be kind enough and let me know how can I achieve to send both `account` and `accountHierarchy` at the same level?

Comment: You're doing yourself (and others like us who are being asked to look at it) a disservice by not laying out the code properly so it can easily be seen what the structure is. I've updated your post, but please format it properly yourself next time.

Comment: Sorry for that... and you're totally right. Thanks for the patience and for taking your time on formatting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a non-ref SOAP::Data->value on top...

```
sub callservice{
...
$params =
    SOAP::Data->value(
      SOAP::Data->name(
        'accountHierarchy' => \SOAP::Data->value(

            SOAP::Data->name( 'customerId' => '250001' ),

            SOAP::Data->name( 'currencyCodeId' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                SOAP::Data->name( 'domain' => 'ACC' ),
                SOAP::Data->name( 'value' => 'EUR' )

            ) )
        )
    ),

    SOAP::Data->name(
        'account' => \SOAP::Data->value(

            SOAP::Data->name( 'customerId' => '250001' ),

            SOAP::Data->name( 'languageCodeId' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                SOAP::Data->name( 'domain' => 'ACC' ),
                SOAP::Data->name( 'value' => 'en' )

            ) ),

            SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleProgression' => \SOAP::Data->value(

                SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleEntry' => \SOAP::Data->value(
                    SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleSubState'=> 'STD' ),
                    SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleReasonCode'=> 'ADD' ),
                    SOAP::Data->name( 'lifeCycleState'=> 'ACTIVE' )
                ) )

            )),

            SOAP::Data->name( 'paymentResponsibility' => 'true' ),

            SOAP::Data->name( 'accountName' => 'TLA13134' ),

            SOAP::Data->name( 'accountType' => 'CONVERGENT' )

        )
    )
);

$response = $service->call("createChildSubscriptionAccount", $params);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

And now that it's formatted, the problem becomes more obvious.

You are assigning two values to the scalar `$params`, and only the last one is used as that is the last statement evaluated by the comma operator. My `SOAP::Lite` knowledge is extremely rusty so I'm not sure whether you can wrap both in an array ref:

```
$params = [
    SOAP::Data->name( accountHierarchy => ... ),
    SOAP::Data->name( account => ... ),
];
```

Or whether you have to use the proper `SOAP::Lite` mechanism to create some anonymous array. But that'll get you going again.

Comment: Hi Leeft, thanks for your answer. I tried that one already but no luck as what it does it add a "      <soapenc:Array soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[2]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">" at the request root :( and that doesn't work either... I will keep looking around though... thanks a lot!